# Add handler to the resolver of GCP secret manager in Spring application

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have a Spring boot application running on GCP cloud run that accesses the secrets stored on GCP. I am using the library spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:4.8.4 to perform the secret resolution during application bootstrapping.

The secrets are injected in the @Configuration bean using @Value("${sm://my-secret}").
Locally, I am able to resolve the values, however, when I deploy the application the injection of secret is not happening instead I just get the value as "//my-secret" i.e. just the prefix "sm:" is removed. I do not see any errors logged as well.

In order to further triage the issue, I needed to add a handler to the gcp-starter-secretmanager to identify where the issue may lie.

Had anyone faced such issue? Any guidance on how to get a hook into the GCP secret manager library secret resolution workflow?